# How do I create a function that gets called automatically syntactically?

Tags: javascript

In most game engines there is an update event that can be written as a function, However i dont know how to create something like this in javascript so i was wondering if anyone know how to create such a system

Comment: with `setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame`

Comment: @FredStark Im looking for a global way of implementing this not a local way

Comment: those are global. All JS game engines end up using these under the hood to call all registered update functions

Comment: How do you register those update functions, because you need a way to update those per object created

Comment: That depends on the framework. Some, like ThreeJS, don't hold your hand and you need to do that yourself. I tend to create a game object graph that matches the scene graph and iterate over each child calling `update` on each one before rendering the scene

Comment: I think i just thought up a kindof hacky way of doing this which is creating a function that acts as a C++ main function in Javascript and whenever a new class is created it binds itself to the main function, which has a loop attached to it. Basically making javascript act 100% like C++. what do you think?

Comment: Yeah that works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have a "tick rate" to speak of. Any system that would provide regular updates to an element would need to update at a certain interval.

You can have a main event loop that calls for updates on any number of other functions and in this way create a system that behaves like a game engine, for example:

```
var mainEventLoop = setInterval(function() { // This will begin running as soon as the page loads

   // Then, all of the functions you want to run at this interval can be included here:
     updatePlayerSprite();

 if (enemyActive === true){
     updateEnemySprites();
     }
 if (prevPlayerHealth > currentPlayerHealth){
     updatePlayerHealthBar(currentPlayerHealth);
     }

    // etc.

    },50); // This (arbitrary example) number is the time in ms between each update
```

RPG Maker MV has built its entire engine on JS. It's fairly solid for easing into eventing and JS as most of the interface is visually-based but it allows you to execute your own custom JS as well. If you want to get a look at how a standalone JS application handles an entire game engine, it frequently goes on sale on Steam for ~$20.